# React: Mixing javascript with jsx

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple method which returns jsx that looks as follows:

```
renderNewsItems = newsItems => {
    return(
        newsItems.map(newsItem => 
        <NewsItem title={newsItem.title} imageUrl={newsItem.imageUrl} />)
    );
  }
```

and this works fine however when I try to add markup to layout the individual `<NewsItem />` components, I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to work. My current, broken attempt looks as follows:

```
renderNewsItems = newsItems => {
    return(
        <div className="row">
            newsItems.map(newsItem => 
            <div className="col-4">
                <NewsItem title={newsItem.title} imageUrl={newsItem.imageUrl} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

which results in the error:

> 'newsItem' is not defined  no-undef

In case it's not clear, I'm trying to use the bootstrap grid system to set the layout for how my individual `<NewsItem/>` components should be rendered

Comment: You're not returning anything when mapping...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Write it:

```
renderNewsItems = newsItems => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      {newsItems.map(newsItem => (
        <div className="col-4">
          <NewsItem
            key={newsItem.id}
            title={newsItem.title}
            imageUrl={newsItem.imageUrl}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Note: I assume you have `id` property on `newsItem`. If you don't have, you can use `title` too as `key` value, until they are uniq across the all the array elements.